# SQL INSERT based on SELECT results

Tags: sql, insert

Forgive me as I'm relatively new to SQL.  But I'm trying to take modified data from a SELECT query on one table, and use it to populate data into another table.

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE=10
```

I want to insert the resultant ID's into another Table, but with modifications such that the value is:

```
1stString.ID.2ndString
```

I've found answers for how to use the ID from the SELECT in the insert, but I can't seem to get it working when trying to concatenate.  There are also other values that I'm inserting, but they're literals (I'm trying to initialize default key settings for the ID's given in another table.

Using MS SQL Studio 2008, btw.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (field)
SELECT '1stString.' + cast(id as varchar(50)) + '.2ndString' 
FROM table2 
WHERE id = 10
```

Edit - response to comment:
You're on the right track, but you want to select your hard-coded strings from your table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT '1stVal', '2ndVal', '1stString.' + cast(id as varchar(50)) + '.2ndString' 
FROM table2 
WHERE id = 10
```

This is also illustrated in Dustin Laine's answer.

Comment: Does SQL Studio still use + for string concatenation? If not, it would be ||.

Comment: This appears to be a pretty sound solution.  What if I need to insert more values, that are NOT from table2?

Comment: ^Last comment got cut off.  For instance though, if I want to put "1","String",'1stString.'+cast(id as varchar(50)) + '.2ndString'   into the various columns of the table, where the only info coming from table2 is "id".  Would it just be        INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3) 'firstval','2ndval',SELECT '1stString.' + cast(id as varchar(50)) + '.2ndString' FROM table2 WHERE otherID = 10?    Sorry, formatting is tricky with comments...

Answer (score 15):

```
INSERT INTO table1
(
    f1, f2, f3, f4
)
SELECT f1, f2, f3, 'defaultval' as f4
FROM table2
WHERE value = 1
```